# WebRTC audio distortion -- Intermittent and Repeated

Tags: audio, webrtc, google-hangouts

When engaging in a hangout (or via custom webrtc application) on a video and audio call, one caller will observe distortion in the affected party's audio. This distortion will directly correlate to the `packetsSentPerSecond` (as observed from `chrome://webrtc-internals` (from the affected side))
[image: packetsSentPerSecond pattern]

I've observed this pattern on two separate machines. Both Windows 7, (8 to 10) with Chrome 45.0.2454.93 m. The audio interface has been varying, with both internal and USB interfaces tested. Once it occurs, it continues to occur more repeatedly. The pattern also seems to reset. In the above figure, the valleys increase in frequency, and seemingly reset (~9:13) and repeat that pattern.

Wondering if anyone has seen a similar problem or has any thoughts on how this can be further diagnosed.

Comment: I am guessing you are just using the default OPUS settings in the SDP right?

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: Yeah, different hardware